# Where is the _imp module located in Python 3.4?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to understand how relative imports work with regular packages, and I was looking at my Python 3.4.3 folder for examples. In a file called machinery.py that I found in C:\Python34\Lib\importlib (I installed 3.4 in C:\Python34), I found this line:

```
import _imp
```

Where is this module located? Just curious about it. I tried doing the cmd search `dir _imp.py /s` on my Windows laptop from C:\Python34, but I didn't find anything. Out of a wild guess, I was thinking it may be some low level C library, so I tried searching with `dir _imp.lib /s`, but I didn't get anything there either.

Comment: `_imp.__file__` says?

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams I didn't know about that attribute. I got an AttributeError though in the interpreter. randomir said it was a built-in module. Is that why this error would appear?

Comment: That would be one cause of that exception, yes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As `help(_imp)` says:

> _imp - (Extremely) low-level import machinery bits as used by importlib and imp.

It's a built-in module:

```
>>> _imp
<module '_imp' (built-in)>
```

and the source can be found in [`Python/import.c`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cba9a0c6def70549046f1afa6a80e38fe706520e/Python/import.c).

Comment: That's interesting. Didn't think of looking at the actual cpython source. But that makes sense, considering it's "built-in". Does Python look in one of the .lib library files provided with the python installation for a built-in module like this? I'm guessing in my installation, it would be in either in `libs\python3.lib` or `libs\python34.lib`, looking at the names.

Comment: I'm not sure how it's on Windows, but on Linux this module is linked in the `python3` binary. You can check it if you search for a specific string from the module, for example `extension_suffixes`.

Comment: It can't be part of the `python3` binary, since it then wouldn't be available to applications that embed Python. The alternative is for it to be in `libpython3.x.so.1.0` (or its equivalent on the appropriate platform).

Comment: @randomir I don't know how to do that on Windows. I've never thought of doing something like that before. Do you have any ideas on how to do this? Any tips would do. I could look more into it, and ask in another question if I need help. Nonetheless, I got my question answered. Thanks.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams, that actually varies across distributions. Fedora links to `libpython`, Debian/Ubuntu doesn't (see [here](https://mail.python.org/pipermail/distutils-sig/2016-February/028275.html)). On my machine both `python3.5` and `libpython3.5` export ~2k functions/objects, and `python3.5` binary *does not* use/links to `libpython3.5`.

Comment: @DragonautX, it turns out the location of built-in modules/functions depends on the build process and it varies even across various Linux dists. On Windows, you can use [Sysinternals tools](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/sysinternals-suite), for eg. [Process Explorer](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/process-explorer) to see linked/depended objects for Python binary, and [Strings](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/downloads/strings) to dump all strings from a binary. To see exported symbols, you can use Visual Studio (`dumpbin` tool).

Comment: @randomir Thanks for the links! I'll try them out. Maybe comment back here if I find the location.