# error 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll Additional information: No module named _imp

Tags: c#

i got this error when i run my python code with c#,

An unhandled exception of type 'IronPython.Runtime.Exceptions.ImportException' occurred in Microsoft.Dynamic.dll

Additional information: No module named _imp

how to solve this error, please help me
this is my code
`Process process = new Process(); //to make a process call
            ScriptEngine engine = Python.CreateEngine(); //For Engine to initiate the script
            List<string> pathes = engine.GetSearchPaths().ToList();
            pathes.AddRange(new[]
            {
              @"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python.exe",@"E:\Work\MaskGenerate\MaskGenerate\bin\Debug",
              @"E:\Work\MaskGenerate\MaskGenerate\bin\Debug\image.py",@"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\python35.zip",
              @"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\DLLs",@"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib",@"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5",
              @"C:\Program Files\Python 3.5\lib\site-packages",@"E:\Work\MaskGenerate\MaskGenerate\Lib"
            });
            engine.SetSearchPaths(pathes);
            var b = engine.GetBuiltinModule();
            var a = engine.GetClrModule();
            //dynamic logging = engine.ImportModule("cv2");
            //engine.ExecuteFile(@"./image.py");//Path of my .py file that I would like to see running in console after running my .cs file from VS.//process.StandardInput.Flush();
            var source = engine.CreateScriptSourceFromFile(@"E:\Work\MaskGenerate\MaskGenerate\bin\Debug\image.py");
            var scope = engine.CreateScope();
            CompiledCode compiled = source.Compile();
            compiled.Execute(scope);
            var classCalculator = scope.GetVariable("image");
            //initializing class
            var calculatorInstance = engine.Operations.CreateInstance(classCalculator);
            pictureBox1.Image = calculatorInstance.getimage();`

Comment: It is caused by the content of image.py, we can't see it.  [Look here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46739170/where-is-the-imp-module-located-in-python-3-4)

Comment: import cv2
class image:
   def getimage(self):
       img = cv2.imread('abc.jpg',0)
       return img

Comment: this is my python code                                                                                                               import cv2
class image:
   def getimage(self):
       img = cv2.imread('abc.jpg',0)
       return img

Comment: please help me for find the solution